# Deference operators to build up 2d array of strings in C

Tags: c, string

The below code outputs a segmentation fault :11

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 int main(){
 char **total;
 strcpy(*(total+1),"hello");
 printf("%s",*(total+1));
 }
```

But while the below one(when initialised without **Array)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
char total[3][100];
strcpy(total[1],"hello");
printf("%s",total[1]);
}
```

So what exactly went wrong in the first code? Is it due to the initialisation step or the strcpy function?

Comment: "*Pointers are not Arrays!*"

Comment: `char **total;` --> `char (*total)[100] = malloc(3*sizeof(*total));` (and put `#include <stdlib.h>` then `free(total);` after use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't allocated the memory at all.

```
char **total = malloc(3*sizeof(char*));
for(int i=0; i!=3; ++i) total[i]=malloc(100*sizeof(char));
```

Do not forget to deallocate it:

```
for(int i=0; i!=3; ++i) free(total[i]);
free(total);
```

Accessing using pointer arithmetic does the same thing, however they can confuse readers. You can use the same array index syntax on pointers.

Also note that statically allocating using the array syntax is different from using pointers and malloc. The first allocates on stack, while the later is allocating on heap.

Comment: A `char**` does not point to a `char[N][M]`.

Comment: @alk oops, fixed it.

Comment: @alk Can you correct your downvote since the answer is improved?

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP apparently wants to allocate a 2D array dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

using `char total[3][100]` automatically reserve a part of memory for your array called total.
using `char **total` you must allocate the memory for your array.

Comment: I feel this is "somewhat" unclear ...

Comment: What is unclear?? @alk

Comment: I failed to parse your answer, due to the complete lack of punctuation.